# Determine how many time intervals intersect with every given time interval (R)

Tags: r, interval-tree

I am working with [these data](https://github.com/pazos-feren/Data/blob/main/contracts.csv) on R. These are the first six rows —without counting the first column, which the write.csv function always adds—:

```
> head(my_data)
client_id contract_id contract_start contract_end inter_complex
        1           1     15/07/2019   15/07/2020  18092+18458i
        3           3      1/01/2015    1/01/2015  16436+16436i
        5           5     12/06/2020   12/06/2020  18425+18425i
       13          13      1/01/2015    1/01/2015  16436+16436i
       18          18      1/01/2015    1/01/2015  16436+16436i
       19          19      1/01/2015    1/01/2015  16436+16436i
```

**Each row represents a different contract.** The variable *inter_complex* is a complex number whose real part is the numeric representation of the date when a contract started, and whose imaginary part analogously represents the date when a contract ended. In case you're wondering, you can obtain that column by executing this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

chars_2_cplex = function(start, end) {
    cbind(start, end) %>%
    apply(2, compose(as.numeric, dmy)) %*% rbind(1, 1i)
}

my_data %>% transmute(inter_complex = chars_2_cplex(contract_start, contract_end))
```

**What I want is, for each client id and each contract, to identify how many contracts associated to that same client id intersect with that contract.** In other words: I want to create a new column called *simultaneous* which will depict for each row —i.e. for each contract— how many active contracts the corresponding client has during the very same period that the current contract is active. **In case no intersection with any other contract is found for a given contract, then the value of *simultaneous* would have to be 1** —as while that contract is active it is also the only active contract that the respective client has—.

I figured it would help to obtain the combinations of *inter_complex*, then turn those combinations of complex numbers into combinations of intervals, and then use lubridate's intersect function to discern whether or not each combination of intervals intersect. For that purpose, I have written the following code:

```
## This function turns complex numbers into intervals.
cplex_2_inter = function(x) {
    start = x %>% Re() %>% as.integer()
    end = x %>% Im() %>% as.integer()

    interval(as_date(start), as_date(end))
}


## This other function returns a list whose j-th element is a data frame that shows the interceptions
## between combinations of j + 1 intervals.
get_intersections = function(x) {
    max_m = length(x)
    output = vector(mode = "list", length = max_m - 1)

    for (i in 2:max_m) {
        output[[i - 1]] = combn(x, m = i) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
                          mutate_all(cplex_2_inter) %>% rowid_to_column("id") %>%
                          pivot_longer(-id) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
                          mutate(simultaneous = do.call(lubridate::intersect, as.list(value))) %>%
                          mutate(simultaneous = if_else(as.character(simultaneous) != "NA--NA", i, 1L))
    }

    return(output)
}
```

In order to get a better grasp on what the function get_intersections does, I propose that you run the following:

```
example = my_data %>% filter(client_id == 1) %>% pull(inter_complex) %>% get_intersections()
```

The data frame `example[[1]]` shows whether there are interceptions —or, for a better word, **overlaps**— between pairs of intervals. The data frame `example[[2]]` shows whether there are overlaps between groups of three intervals, and so on.

You may notice that according to `example[[1]]` the interval *2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC* overlaps with some other interval —and hence, the associated value of *simultaneous* is 2— while, according to `example[[2]]`, that very same interval is associated to a value of 3 for the variable *simultaneous*. **Naturally, the idea is to assign to each interval its highest *simultaneous* value.**

Since I do not care about global overlaps but rather about overlaps within each client id I figured I would require to work on a grouped data frame. The furthest I got on this project was writing this:

```
my_data %>% group_by(client_id) %>% group_map(~ get_intersections(.x$inter_complex))
```

Now onto my questions. **1)** I have executed the line above, but the process is not very efficient. It has already run for a bit more than a whole day and it doesn't finish yet. Recently I came across the concept of interval trees but I'm not a computer scientist and I would require help in order to tackle this problem in a smarter way. **2)** In case we stick to my not-so-smart approach to the problem, I would still require a function that accesses each element of the list that is returned by *get_intersections*, so as to identify and retrieve the highest *simultaneous* value associated to each interval. On that matter I would have to request help as well.

### Edit

Regarding Wimpel's answer, I have examined their data table and I found this.

```
> DT %>% filter(client_id == 502 & contract_id == 3093) %>%
> select(contract_start, contract_end, contract_intersect)
# Output
   contract_start contract_end contract_intersect
1:     2018-01-11   2019-01-11                  7
```

That is, the displayed contract allegedly overlaps with **seven** other contracts that the same client has.

On the other hand, let's see if this holds true when using my combinations-based approach.

```
combs_10_502 = my_data %>% filter(client_id == 502) %>% pull(inter_complex) %>% 
               combn(10) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate_all(cplex_2_inter) %>% 
               rowid_to_column("id") %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
               mutate(simultaneous = do.call(lubridate::intersect, as.list(value))) %>% 
               ungroup() %>% 
               mutate(simultaneous = if_else(as.character(simultaneous) != "NA--NA", 10L, 1L))    

> combs_10_502 %>% filter(simultaneous == 10) %>% slice(11:20)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
  id    name  value                          simultaneous
  <int> <chr> <Interval>                            <int>
1  24311 V1    2018-01-11 UTC--2019-01-11 UTC        10
2  24311 V2    2018-03-01 UTC--2019-03-01 UTC        10
3  24311 V3    2018-07-11 UTC--2019-07-11 UTC        10
4  24311 V4    2018-04-20 UTC--2019-04-20 UTC        10
5  24311 V5    2018-05-21 UTC--2019-05-21 UTC        10
6  24311 V6    2018-08-10 UTC--2019-08-10 UTC        10
7  24311 V7    2018-08-09 UTC--2019-08-09 UTC        10
8  24311 V8    2018-09-27 UTC--2019-09-27 UTC        10
9  24311 V9    2020-01-03 UTC--2021-01-03 UTC        10
10 24311 V10   2019-12-19 UTC--2020-12-19 UTC        10
```

The same contract is displayed on the first row of the tibble above. As can be seen, that contract actually overlaps with **nine** other contracts of the given client —those nine are displayed on the remaining rows—.

I don't know how Wimpel's solution got this wrong, but I checked that it does get the number of intersections right for several other contracts. Now I know that a data table-based solution is what I am looking for, since the processes are made very fast, but there seems to be an issue with the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pazos-feren/Data/main/contracts.csv")
#set dates as real dates
DT[, contract_start := as.Date(contract_start, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]
DT[, contract_end := as.Date(contract_end, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]

setkey(DT, V1)

DT[DT, c("contract_intersect", "contract_intersect_ids") := {
  val = DT[ !V1 == i.V1 & client_id == i.client_id &
              contract_start <= i.contract_end & contract_end >= i.contract_start, ]
  list( nrow(val), paste0(val$contract_id, collapse = ";") )
}, by = .EACHI]

#    V1 client_id contract_id contract_start contract_end inter_complex contract_intersect contract_intersect_ids
# 1:  1         1           1     2019-07-15   2020-07-15  18092+18458i                  2              4162;4168
# 2:  2         3           3     2015-01-01   2015-01-01  16436+16436i                  0                       
# 3:  3         5           5     2020-06-12   2020-06-12  18425+18425i                  0                       
# 4:  4        13          13     2015-01-01   2015-01-01  16436+16436i                  0                       
# 5:  5        18          18     2015-01-01   2015-01-01  16436+16436i                  0                       
# 6:  6        19          19     2015-01-01   2015-01-01  16436+16436i                  0
```

Comment: I just edited my original post so as to address an issue I found in your solution. Besides that, I really appreciated your answer and it seems you are very close to solving the problem. Would you please give it another look?

Comment: reading your edit, is see something that I have questions abount: row 1 `1  24311 V1    2018-01-11 UTC--2019-01-11 UTC        10` does not overlap row 9 and/or 10 `10 24311 V10   2019-12-19 UTC--2020-12-19 UTC        10`. Why are those contracts in your list of overlaps?